# How to search a subarray of numbers inside an array of numbers

Tags: arrays, typescript, sub-array

my issue is this in TypeScript (now latest is v3.1)

I have a array of numbers

```
let mainArray : Array<number>  = [1,2,3,4];
```

I have to find subarray of [2,3], how can i do?

My actual workaround is converting both arrays in string (toString()) and using .includes (ES6) function, and it works but i think is not the best solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to find the exact `piece` of 2,3 in that main array or we are looking for any combination like 3,2 or 2,3? The string approach you took works only for the first case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter for this

```
      let mainArray : Array<number>  = [1,2,3,4];
      var findArry = [2, 3];
      var subArray =   mainArray.filter(function(val) {
            return findArry.indexOf(val) != -1 ? true : false;
        });
    console.log(subArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well its more algorithm problem then typescript problem. But this solution should work for checking if there is subarray which matched with searched array:

```js
const toTuples = (n) => (item, index, originalArr) => {
 const arr = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   arr.push(originalArr[index + i]);
  }
  return arr;
}

const arr = [1,2,3,4,2,3];

const search = [2, 3];

const mapped = arr.map(toTuples(search.length));

console.log(mapped.some((currArray) => currArray.every((item) => search.includes(item))));
```

Comment: yes i agree, i meant to ask if existed a factory function (es6?) to find a subarray

Comment: I am not sure what do you meean by “factory function”. But as far as i know there is no such method which can do this work for you. Meybe some library can do this.